# Install multiple softwares with one installer (install wrapper?)

Tags: installation, wrapper, distribution

I'm looking for a solution to run multiple setup files (.exe and .msi) in sequence without any user input.  The idea is to have everyone in my workgroup to have the same development tools (eclipse, python, cygwin, etc) by running one installer.  Besides creating a batch script, is there a software out there that could create such a wrapper of installers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my knowledge there aren't any tools which create this type of wrappers, or if there are they are not MSI-based. This is because Windows Installer is very restrictive when it comes to running multiple installers simultaneously.

You can try using a setup authoring tool which supports package prerequisites. This way you can create a dummy package which installs nothing, but still handles all the applications you want installed.

If you want some suggestions don't hesitate to contact me.